# What is "greetings programs"?

Tags: meaning

It is from this [video](https://youtu.be/REVpwKKd8VA). It is at 14 second. Here it is:

> **Greetings programs**, Trace here for DNews.

I searched it on the internet, but could not find what it means. What is it from and what does it mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It might be a nod to the 1982 movie *Tron* the main protagonist uses it as a greeting fairly often.

**Kevin Flynn:** Greetings, programs.

Comment: You beat me to it by 1 minute.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a joke, perhaps an "in joke" that would be understood by regular subscribers to the youtube channel.

Perhaps it's a parody of "Greetings, Earthlings", the greeting made by aliens from outer space in schlock films. Perhaps it is some joke along the lines of "Lots of the hits on my videos come from search engines." Or a nerd joke "Did you know that the brain could be simulated by a computer program?"

It's very common for YouTubers and others to stick some weird catch-phrase near the beginning, that they think is very clever. Sometimes it's just gibberish. Don't waste any brain cells trying to understand it.